# Using DownloadManager to get download status

Tags: android

I've searched a lot but i can't find a satisfying answer.
I've simply created a method that when called, print in Log.i() all available downloads status; Here's the method:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();              
Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);

while (c.moveToNext()) {
            switch(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
                  case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download failed!");
                    break;

                  case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download paused!");
                    break;

                  case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download pending!");
                    break;

                  case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download in progress!");
                    break;

                  case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download complete!");
                    break;

                  default:
                      Log.i("46dl","Download is nowhere in sight");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But this only works if i start a download from my app; E.g.

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse("http://www.something.com/img/img4.jpg"));
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

For other files downloading with other apps(e.g. with browser ) no lines was write in Log.
Am i missing something? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the download status of downloads done by other apps.
This is protected.

Comment: Hi, i haven't downvote; there's any way to get when the last download has finish? Becouse i'm working on an app that when all the downloads are done it switch off connection. Thanks!

Comment: Not with the DownloadManager, on rooted device it is possible. With the public URI: content://downloads/all_downloads/2334 you can get the file (everybody can acces). But you don't know the progress.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? If Android has changed the api I will change the answer. But this was/is not possible at the time of posting.