# How to get notified when download manager finishes all downloads

Tags: android

I use the DownloadManager to check if there is an ongoing downloads, and it works fine (I thought it works fine, please see the Edit below).

what I need is to get notified once DownloadManager finishes all the downloads (Requested by other apps as Google Play for example) so in my application I'll take a specific action.

Edit1:

The below code always go to (else, cursor is always empty) even though there is a current download by other applications, why? does it check if there is a download asked by my application only or if there is a download in general?

Edit2:

I found the same problem in (Edit1) here [Using DownloadManager to get download status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574979/using-downloadmanager-to-get-download-status) , and the answer was 'You cannot get the download status of downloads done by other apps. This is protected.'

```
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                DownloadManager.Query query = null;

                Cursor c = null;

                query = new DownloadManager.Query();

                 if(query!=null) 
                 {
                    query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL|
                                            DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);

                    c = downloadManager.query(query);

                    if(c.moveToFirst()) 
                    { 
                    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)); 
                    switch(status) 
                    { 
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED: 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "STATUS_PAUSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 

                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING: 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "STATUS_PENDING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 

                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING: 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "STATUS_RUNNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //Here I want to wait until no more downloads to make an action, how to wait.

                    break; 

                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL: 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 

                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED: 
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "STATUS_FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Download In Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       //Here I'll make some action, but the problem that even when there is a download in progress, else if being called, why?!
                    }

                    c.close();
                 }
```

Comment: I recall seeing some source about displaying noti to an android device on a gcm client tutorial source. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html The sendNotification function implemented below that page may provide you most of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching over the internet I found that it's not possible to detect the DownloadManager status except for my own downloads.